# How to use documents from different collections in a stream builder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch two documents from 2 different Firestore collections and use them in a stream builder. I am trying to achieve something similar to the Instagram home feed where the username is above each post.

For example I have 2 collections

1 - Users and a document example is:

```
u123:{ //docId
"uid": "a123", // string
"username": "john", // string
"age":24, // int
}
```

2- Posts and a document

```
p123:{ //postId
"id": "b123", // string
"title": "foo", // string
"picUrl": "https://..."
"uid":"/Users/u123", // document reference
}
```

My question is, is it possible to fetch the posts as well as the users and use them in the stream builder?

Answer (score 0):

Loading the user that is referenced by the `DocumentReference` in the `uid` field of a `Post` requires an extra call to `get()` or `snapshots()` on that `DocumentReference`. Firestore does not support server-side joining of the data.